# GIMP: how to rotate a picture from its end

Tags: gimp

Hello I want to rotate a picture in gimp but I want the axis to be at the end of the picture. Kind of like a picture being a knife in a folding knife. I want to be able to rotate a picture like that. Anyone know how to? Cheers.

Look at the picture ( I want to rotate the photo from the white point) meaning I want it to spin with the axis at the white point.)[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rotate an object in Gimp (here 2.8.) using the rotate tool we have to add it as a *"Floating Selection"*, or we make any selection (which can also be the whole image) float with *Select > Float* (or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>).

We can then move the center of rotation by dragging it with the mouse to the desired postition, or by giving the exact coordinates relative to the canvas in the *Rotate* dialog (per default or on pressing <kbd>Reset</kbd> this will be the center of the object):

[image]